# BigQuery Error 6034920 when using UPDATE FROM

Tags: google-bigquery

We are trying to perform an ELT in BigQuery. When using **UPDATE FROM**, it fails on some tables with the following error:

> "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
>   Error: 6034920"

Moreover, both (Source and Destination) tables consists of data from a single partition.

We are unable to find the details for error code 6034920. Any insight/solutions would be really appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is transient, internal error on Bigquery. This behavior is related to a BigQuery shuffling component (in the BQ service backend) and engineers are working to solve it. At the moment there is not an ETA to have this resolved.

In the meantime, as a workaround you should retry the query to detect this behavior again. You can continue tracking the logs in Stackdriver related to this issue by using the following filter:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatus.additionalErrors.message="An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 6034920"
```

What you can try, is to stop putting values into the partitioning column, it could hopefully fixed the job failures. I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: Is there a place where the progress on this bug can be tracked?

Comment: Please, track this [bug](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/117851070) to see the status of the issue.

Comment: Thanks @muscat. Is the bug tracking only available for google employees ?

Comment: @Bryan yes, it is, but also for customer. I will let you know about updates. You can open public [issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Comment: Hi @muscat, I have opened a bug in the Google Issue Tracker. I did notice a couple of bugs logged related to this error code, one of them is marked as solved but no solution is provided (related to TensorFlow). Thanks very much for your help.